# vBulletin Custom Registration Code Not working

Tags: php, sql, vbulletin

I need to create a custom registration form for my vBulletin page. I only need to figure out how to call the user save API for vBulletin and update the database.

I have already written a code that I thought should work, but it is not. my VBbUlletin is version 5.3.3 and without any customization.

```
<?php
// Path to vBulletin installation
$vbpath = 'forum';

// Start script
require_once( $vbpath . '/includes/vb5/autoloader.php' );
vB5_Autoloader::register( $vbpath );

//init the vBulletin system
require_once( $vbpath . '/core/vb/vb.php' );
vB::init();

//get user info
$user[ 'username' ] = $_POST[ 'username' ];
$user[ 'email' ] = $_POST[ 'email' ];

//Create new user
$userApi = vB_Api::instance( 'user' );
$userId = $userApi->save( 0, $_POST[ 'password' ], $user, array(), array(), array() );
?>
```